# Javascript - Insert an item in Object

Tags: javascript, object

How to insert an item in an object in `Javascript`?

```
var colorData = new Object();
var stateData = {
           states:
            [
              { 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'},
              { 'state' : 'AZ', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'}
            ]
    }

for (var i = 0; i < stateData.length; i++) {            
       colorData.push(stateData[i].state + ':' + stateData[i].color);            
    }
```

-------------------edited--------------------

I want the new `colorData` in the following format :-

```
{'CA': '#61c419', 'AZ':'#61c419'}
```

Thanks

Comment: hey check out my answer too, its faster than any other method...Anup

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan That is true..

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan your code anyhow work faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** is your friend:

```
var stateData = {
           states:
            [
              { 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'},
              { 'state' : 'AZ', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'}
            ]
    };


var colorData = stateData.states.map(function(ele) {
    return ele.state + ':' + ele.color;
});
```

If you want the result to be `{CA: '#61c419', AZ: '#61c419'}`, then:

```
var colorData = stateData.states.reduce(function(v, w) {
    v[w.state] =  w.color;
    return v; 
}, {});
```

Comment: @Anup The second solution will give you the expected result.

Comment: the result now comes is `AZ: "#61c419", CA: "#61c419"` .... how can we make it to `"AZ": "#61c419", "CA": "#61c419"`?

Comment: @Anup There is no difference between what you said, both are valid syntax for javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/29/)**

```
var colorData = new Object();
var stateData = {
           states:
            [
              { 'state' : 'CA', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'},
              { 'state' : 'AZ', 'color' : '#61c419', 'amaguide' : '5'}
            ]
};
for(var i=0; i<stateData.states.length; i++)
{
    colorData[stateData.states[i].state] = stateData.states[i].color;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(colorData));
```

**Output**

```
{"CA":"#61c419","AZ":"#61c419"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the item to an object property. `.push()` is for arrays.

```
var o = {};
o.newProperty = 'hier';
o.otherProperty = [1, 2, 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Array is better for that:

```
...
var colorData = new Array();
...
```